# Read current NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS session setting

Tags: sql, oracle, sessioncontext

I have to run a report with numeric decimals as parameters in different territories with different `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`, aka comma separators.

`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` is set on the session level eg. with

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
```

Expression `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.'`  means 
the the decimal marker is a comma, and the thousands marker to a point.

To get the user input right in all the different territories I assume that the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` settings of the session is set correctly. I want to evaluate that session state into a field value `s_nlsparam` and use it to convert the report parameters correctly with

```
.. to_number(expr,format, v_nlsparam) ...
```

so far the plan. This would tame any potential `ORA-01722: invalid number` in the multi-national context.

Now I can't find a way to read the current session state of the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` settings.  I checked the view `v$session`, but it doesn't offer any such field. Neither I found such a parameter using:

```
select sys_context('USERENV', .... ) from dual
```

Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Is the transformation not done in oracle? As if the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` is set correctly `to_number(expr)` should work. There should be no need to parse the data yourself...

Comment: It seems the session parameter are somewhat messed up. Therefore I want to check the actual state of the SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS in a session. Further on I would like to pamper the default value given in string accordingly ['10.0' vs '10,0'].

Answer (score 6):

You can see that info using this select:

```
select value 
  from nls_session_parameters
 where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';
```

Comment: OK this shows obviously some DB-Global default values for any session to start. How can I query the acutal session state of that parameter in a given session?

Comment: @olippuner on the contrary, this query return current value per session per user. If you would alter your session value for `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` using `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';` command, you would afterwards see that value in the result of this query, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you really need to know the current value?  Since you are assuming that the setting is set correctly in your user session, it would generally make more sense to use the generic format model in your conversion functions.  For example

```
to_number( some_string, '999999999D99' )
```

will convert a string to a number (add more 9's if you need to support numbers larger than a billion) using whatever the session's decimal point is.  If the session uses the comma as the decimal separator, it will look for a comma.  If the session uses the period as the decimal separator, it will look for a period.  Similarly

```
to_char( some_number, '999G999G999D99' )
```

will convert a number to a string using whatever the group and decimal separator the session uses.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately your approach does not work in a multinational environment. Your TO_CHAR has to work for all users using the report's SQL. These users redisde in different countries with different settings of NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS.

Comment: @olippuner - Multinational environments are exactly why Oracle added the abstractions of the group and decimal separator so that developers didn’t have to figure out whether the user used a period or a comma as the decimal separator.  If the session’s NLS settings are correct, this absolutely does work.